# Why pug is not rendering?

Tags: routes, rendering, pug, server-side-rendering

[these is snip shoot of the root route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6nJX.png)
As you can see from the image, when ever I try to access the root which is "localhost:3000/" is not displaying anything. I don't see any errors what's so ever. and the crazy part is that it's only not working on this route which is the root route other routes work like a charm...any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5351721). Instead copy/paste the code into your question as text. You can edit your question to correct this.